# Format and inline loop Python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a function, that needs to be python 2.6 conform:

```
def find(entity, **kwargs):
    return instance.search(
        set(),
        {'search': '{0}="{1}"'.format(key, kwargs[key]) for key in kwargs}
    )
```

However a python 2.6 sanity checks fails at character position 59, which is the "for" from the loop.
Are inline loops not ok in python 2.6?

Comment: true, that is a duplicate. since I did not know where the problem lay, I could sadly not find that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary comprehension was introduced in Python 2.7. See [PEP 274 -- Dict Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

You can instead construct the dictionary by calling `dict` on a generator expression of keys and values:

```
def find(entity, **kwargs):
    return instance.search(
        set(),
        dict(('search', '{0}="{1}"'.format(key, kwargs[key])) for key in kwargs)
    )
```

However, note that your dictionary will only contain a single key and value since `search` is the only key you've provided and it's not changing across the gen. exp.

Comment: thx! that did the trick!